# Attach event to child elements

Tags: javascript, tabs, onclick

```
<div class="tabContainer">
  <ul class="Tabs" id="tabset">
    <li id="tab1" class="selected" onclick="tabs(this)">Home</li>
    <li id="tab2" onclick="tabs(this)">Tab 2</li>
    <li id="tab3"  onclick="tabs(this)">Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to remove `onclick="tabs(this)"` and turn it into an event. How can I do this?
Currently the below code is my solution which isn't working.

```
var h=$("tabset").children;
for (i=0;i<h.length;i++) h[i].onclick=tabs(this);
```

Oh and no jquery please, but `var $ = function(x){return document.getElementById(x)};`
NOTE: I need the `(this)` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
var lis = document.getElementById('tabset').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++){
    lis[i].onclick = tabs; // inside the function 'this' will refer to the node.
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XYbCJ/3/).

Though you could assign the click-handler to the containing `ul` element:

```
var list = document.getElementById('tabset');
tabset.onclick = list.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tabs(e.target);
}, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XYbCJ/1/).

You could, now I see what you're doing with your function, avoid using `getElementById()` and simply chain:

```
$('tabset').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tabs(e.target);
}, false);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XYbCJ/2/).

With jQuery, as you appeared (prior to an edit) to be trying to use:

```
$('#tabset li').click(function(){
    tabs(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using some `$` function in your code which is not standard. For example if you are using jQuery your code could look like this:

```
$('#tabset li').on('click', tabs);
```

If you don't want to use jQuery then you will have to adapt your selector:

```
var h = document.getElementById('tabset').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    h[i].onclick = tabs;
}
```

or since you declared:

```
var $ = function(x){
    return document.getElementById(x)
};
```

you could also use:

```
var h = $('tabset').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < h.length; i++) {
    h[i].onclick = tabs;
}
```